# rowwise look-up in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table of ranked factors and corresponding values by date, but I'd like to also present the data by rank instead of factor.  In the first step, I determine the corresponding factor for each rank (.fact columns in output), and in the second step, I use the factor to determine the corresponding value for each rank (.val2 column in output).  The actual dataset includes many more dates and factors (names and count vary).  Each row corresponds to the model predicted rank for each factor on a specific date, and the value data is the realized value.

The code below works, but is there a more efficient (and faster) way to accomplish the row wise look-up operations below?  Many of the `data.table` suggestions I've read discourage the use of `.SD[, with=FALSE]`, but I've yet to find another solution.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(Date = c("1/31/2013", "2/28/2013", "3/31/2013", 
                         "4/30/2013", "5/31/2013"), 
                A.rnk = c(5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
                B.rnk = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L), 
                C.rnk = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L), 
                D.rnk = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L),
                E.rnk = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L),
                A.val = rnorm(5), B.val = rnorm(5), 
                C.val = rnorm(5), D.val = rnorm(5),
                E.val = rnorm(5))
nms = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
rnks = as.character(1:5)

# determine the factor (A,B,C) for each rank, by date
dt = dt[, c(rnks):={
  cols = .SD[, paste0(nms, ".rnk"), with=FALSE]
  cols = names(cols)[order(cols)]
  as.list(stringr::str_extract(cols, stringr::perl(".{1}(?=.rnk)")))
}, by=Date]

# determine the factor value (val) for each rank, by date
dt[, paste0(rnks, ".val2"):=
     .SD[, paste0(.SD[, rnks, with=FALSE], ".val"), with=FALSE], by=Date]
```

Comment: too much stuff going on - I have no idea what your question is - please simplify it to the essential bits only

Comment: in what sense do you want to summarize?  Do you want to simply 'filter' those results? Do you want to compute some concept of an average? Please be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've attempted to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete rewrite. For your requirements, it's better to work with the data in *long format*, as shown below. It uses `reshape2` package which has the functions `melt` and `dcast` to convert the data into long and wide format respectively.

> Note that faster versions of `melt` and `dcast` are implemented (in C) in the current development version (1.8.11) of `data.table`. So, after the next release of `data.table`, you can use the same code, but you don't have to convert it back to a `data.table` (done using `as.dat.table` shown below) after the `melt` and `dcast` step `+` it'll be a lot faster.

Now on to the solution:

```
# loading packages
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)

# long format on just the .rnk columns
dt.m <- as.data.table(melt(dt, id="Date", measure=2:6))
setnames(dt.m, c("Date", "var1", "val1"))
dt.m[, c("var2", "val2") := as.data.table(melt(dt, id="Date", 
               measure=7:11))[, list(variable, value)]]
# sort by date column by reference
setkey(dt.m, Date)

# here you can alternatively use `order`, but `fastorder` is well, faster
oo <- data.table:::fastorder(as.list(dt.m)[c("Date","val1")])
dt.m[, val3 := rep(nms, length.out=length(oo))[oo]]
dt.m[, val4 := val2[val1], by=Date]

ans1 <- as.data.table(dcast(dt.m, Date ~ var1, value.var="val3"))[, Date := NULL]
ans2 <- as.data.table(dcast(dt.m, Date ~ var2, value.var="val4"))[, Date := NULL]
setnames(ans1, rnks)
setnames(ans2, paste(rnks, ".val2", sep=""))
cbind(dt, ans1, ans2)
```

Comment: This worked great--I saw a 4x improvement in speed using `data.table` 1.8.11.  I wasn't able to get `fastorder` to work, but I think this is due to the Date column type.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I tried the solution with 1.8.11 and posted here for 1.8.10. So, I'm not sure why `fastorder` doesn't work. You'll have to use the `:::` operator as it's not exported.

Comment: Also note that if you're using 1.8.11, then you'll need to use `dcast.data.table` (instead of just `dcast`) to use the faster method there... as it's not yet a S3 generic.

Comment: Probably paste your code that gives error on pastebin and share the link here?

Comment: @user338714, Aha, got it. That's due to recent internal changes in `data.table`.. It's basically because your input is already sorted. Add `if (is.null(oo)) oo <- seq_len(nrow(dt.m))` after the `oo <- data.table:::fastorder(..)` line and you should be good to go.